# How do you include source file/code when sharing a Project with SVN Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I downloaded and installed the latest SVN plugin for Eclipse.  I have a Project that I want to Share.  I right-clicked on my Project's name, selected Team --> Share Project.  This worked like a charm and all my files were checked into the repository.  However, I noticed that my Java source code was not included in the repository.  In my Eclipse project I have the Java Build Path linked to a separate folder. I like to keep my source code in a separate directory.  How do I get SVN to recognize and add this folder to the repository?

Thank you for all your help and advice.

Comment: Subclipse or Subversive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my understanding is, that the folder you would like to add is not a sub-folder of the root folder of your project. In that case, you may find an answer in svn externals:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html